# How to save DHCP option 43 on Windows 2008 server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, dhcp, dhcp-option

I need to retrieve the DHCP option 43 from my DHCP server (Linux ISC DHCP server) on a Windows 2008 server (or any other Windows version, as long as the code 43 is specified in the Parameter request list (code 55)).

I can see the wanted value with Wireshark on Windows in the DHCP Offer packet

```
Option: (t=43; l=30) Vendor-Specific Information
  Option: (43) Vendor-Specific Information
  Length: 30
  Value: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx (some hex number)
```

The converted hex value to string gives me the information I want.

But I don't know where / how to store it on disk ?

I thought I could see it while doing

`ipconfig /all`

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 2):

You're on the DHCP server, correct?

Try `netsh dhcp server show optionvalue`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision, but the DHCP server is a Linux ISC DHCP. My windows server is receiving information from that Linux DHCP server. I'm updating the original post.

Comment: I don't think that it's available, in that case - the DHCP client has no use for an option that it doesn't pay attention to.

Answer (score 0):

The information you are looking for is stored on the register under:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Interfaces\{ID}

{ID} depends of your machine. How I find it is opening the regedit and looking for the entry 'DhcpInterfaceOptions'.

This little code on ruby will pick the registry for you"

```
    require 'win32/registry'

    keyname= "SYSTEM\\ControlSet001\\services\\Tcpip\\Parameters\\Interfaces\\{A0ACCA78-1CB2-46BD-B2E0-B0E791ABFC3B}"
    access = Win32::Registry::KEY_ALL_ACCESS
    Win32::Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.open(keyname) do |reg|;
      key = reg.read_bin('DhcpInterfaceOptions').unpack('H*')
      puts key   
    end
```